# PHP Add decimal time interval

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to do some modification of DateTime objects.  I'm trying to add an amount of time to an existing date.  I know that I can do something like this:

```
$myDate->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
```

to add a year to the time and that works fine.  However, in this case I have calculated times that may not always be even (i.e. it could be .723 years or something).  As a test I tried passing 'P0.5Y' but it gives me an exception that says 'Unknown or bad format' on the constructor for DateInterval...

What is the best way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of calculation you're doing that produces this date interval (e.g. 0.723 years)? I think the solution is probably to do the calculation using smaller time units.

Comment: why don't you convert years to months and add that way

Comment: I don't think fractional years and months make sense, because the length of a year depends on whether it's a leap year, and months have different numbers of days.

Comment: Basically for people to extend a subscription, but in some cases it needs to line up with a specific existing date, so it calculates the amount as a pro-rated portion of a year...  I guess I can convert to days and round, that would work...